# Is NuGet Microsoft.AspNet.WebAPI 5.2.3 a WebAPI 2.2?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, nuget, asp.net-web-api2

There are some confusion of versions of Web API. Check out this [Web API at NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi/),

> Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 2.2   5.2.3

What? Here is the description with no where mentioning 2.2 [image: Package description inside VS 2015]

My guess is the NuGet package itself is 5.2.3 but it complies/supports with Web API standard/version 2.2. And this package is all it needs for implementing Web API 2.2

I wish to see some improvement soon.

Comment: In more recent version of visual studio it shows up like that. I tested it in VS community 2013 and it shows `Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 2.2` with all the matching details as in the image of your post. I believe what you are seeing is the Package Id not that display Name.

Comment: Or, say Web API on IIS 5.2.3 for Web API 2.2.

Comment: @Nkosi I posted this because there is something not working as expected, so I started checking things around for diff version, etc. If you google, you see 2.2 everywhere but no 5.2.3. ...

Comment: What is the actual issue you are encountering.

Comment: @Nkosi I have multiple GET methods in an API controller, got status 500 complained about not be able sort out which one should be used. So I added Attribute for routing (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42103266/webapi-multiple-get-no-good-w-attribute-routing). Still, so I'm wondering if it's web api 2.2, or "AttributeRounting.WebApi" is needed.

Comment: Ok this is an XY problem. You should update your question with the actual problem. Include any error messages that you get and [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem. Maybe then a proper solution can be found for you. It could be a simple routing issue where multiple routes are conflicting

Comment: @Nkosi I'd like to leave it as it is. Though I'm using VS 2015, if you see the screenshot provided above, it clearly says **v5.2.3**. Pretty sure someone like me will get confuse on this version related to API 2.2.

Comment: That is because Web API 2.2 is part of Asp.Net MVC 5

Comment: Company policy prevents chatting. So, the 5 of 5.2.3 is from MVC 5?

Comment: Yes that is correct. Check the MVC 5 package and notice it also has the same 5.2.3 version number

Comment: Good to know. Out of curiosity, assuming this is the versioning convention, there should be another v5.2.3 for non-IIS, right?

Comment: @Nkosi Also, does 5.2.3 support attribute routing?

Comment: Check the answer I provided for your other post, which I think was your original problem.

Comment: @Nkosi Great, appreciate it! Sticking on this version subject, there is 5.0.0 in here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21071452/webapi-2-attribute-routing-using-http-verb-attributes?rq=1  My guess that minor version 0.0 after 5 shouldn't be the matching API version. Just my two cents.

Comment: That is an older version. They would have all been update to 5.2.3 For web api stuff, 3.2.3 for MVC specific stuff like Razon and Web Pages and 1.1.3 for optimization

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is NuGet Microsoft.AspNet.WebAPI 5.2.3, WebAPI 2.2?

Short answer is Yes.

`Microsoft.AspNet.WebAPI` is the package Id while `Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 2.2` would represent the package name.

Web API 2.2 is part of Asp.Net MVC 5 which is also at version `5.2.3`

Comment: Additionally, API 2.2 that is NuGet Microsoft.AspNet.WebAPI 5.2.3 supports Attribute Routing. So, you don't need this old NuGet package  _AttributeRouting.Core 3.5.6_ .